# Custom Area bl_space_type not possible without building Source exe?

Tags: python, versions

I'm hopeful to create a custom blender bl_space_type say CUSTOMVIEW but I get this error.

```
bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
TypeError: validating class: enum "CUSTOMVIEW" not found in ('EMPTY', 'VIEW_3D', 'TIMELINE', 'GRAPH_EDITOR', 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR', 'NLA_EDITOR', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'CLIP_EDITOR', 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR', 'NODE_EDITOR', 'TEXT_EDITOR', 'LOGIC_EDITOR', 'PROPERTIES', 'OUTLINE)
```

I noticed the EMPTY type and thought well that must be there to create a custom view somehow?
Are there any blender bl_space_type empty examples? or examples of creating an addon that creates a new main area type?

Can someone confirm this is another thing that is not possible in Blender... yet? Is it in 2.8? planned?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not possible and also no plans are yet revealed by any developer to make this possible from the python API only.

Making this part fully in python and supported by the community will not be an easy task. Are you up for it?

Comment: I'm not able to sort that one out sorry. I was looking around and so far have come to the same conclusion it seems like that things should start there so a template for a custom empty space_type is where I would have started decades ago I like to think but who knows  Anyway thanks for the feedback. https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.8/UI/Workshop_Writeup

Comment: Here is a similar conversation: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Lrbbbc/